# How to save data from 2 fields as a JSON string to 1 database table field?

Tags: jform, json

I need help to store data in json format in my DB like `{name:'1', name2:'2'}`.

So far I have this:

model/form/category.xml:

```
<fieldset>
    <field
        name="name"
        type="text"
        label="name"
    />
    <field
        name="name2"
        type="text"
        label="name"
    />
</fieldset>
```

view/category/tmpl/edit.php:

```
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('name'); ?></li>
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('name2'); ?></li>
```

I need to send these 2 fields as a json-encoded string into 1 DB field.

Answer (score 3):

You need both PHP functions to do this work:

**json_encode :**

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

**json_decode:**

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Maybe something like this:

```
<?php
$arr = array ();
$arr[name] = $this->form->getInput('name');
$arr[name2] = $this->form->getInput('name2');     
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: It's not the answer. Joomla uses MVC and you didn't show what code should be placed in model and view/tmpl

Answer (score 2):

Enclose those two fields in a  element in your form xml file.

```
<fields label="COM_COMPONENTNAME_FIELDNAME_FIELDSET_LABEL" name="fieldname">
  <fieldset label="COM_COMPONENTNAME_FIELDNAME_FIELDSET_LABEL" name="basic">
     <field name="name" type="text" label="name"/>
     <field name="name2" type="text" label="name"/>
  </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Now the both fields will go as json data into the table column "fieldname" (change it to your actual fieldname)

Answer (score -1):

json_decode on Model->getItem()

json_encode on Model->save()

```
class CompModelName extends JModelAdmin
{

    public function save($data = array())
    {
        if(isset($data['prices']) && is_array($data['prices'])) $data['prices']=json_encode($data['prices']);
        return parent::save($data);
    }

    public function getItem($pk = null)
    {
        if (!$item = parent::getItem($pk))
        {           
            throw new Exception('Failed to load item');
        }
        $item->prices=json_decode($item->prices,true);
        return $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly include a bit more explanation about why this solution is appropriate and uses best practices?  I don't know if this is a working solution and I wish the downvoter would would have had the courage to leave a comment, but this is nearly a code-only answers.  Code-only answers are low value on Stack Exchange sites because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.